# Resources fo Security Awareness training

Tags: corporate-policy, awareness

as part of security awareness for the company, I am looking for something that I could use to spread the awareness. Maybe a web based application/portal which I can create quiz forms easily or share out media resources on IT security easily. What kind of tools do you use to help spread awareness to the company?

thanks

Comment: Please note that poll-type, open-ended questions are not welcome at Stack Exchange.

Comment: The best way to spread awareness is word-of-mouth and peer pressure, meaning you have a long hard uphill trek before mass psychology takes over.

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Considering all your questions, have you considered hiring a third party to assist you in developing a proper security program, isntead of hacking it all together based on internet resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.securingthehuman.org/.
The newsletters are quite good.

And http://www.cpni.gov.uk/advice/Personnel-security1/.
They have reusable posters and other resources for awareness and training.

Answer (score 1):

If you have software developers and testers check out the courses at Pluralsight. Also troyhunt.com very useful.